# form_for with ckeckbox_tag from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and just cant get that problem solved.

i have 3 models. Orders, Products and LineItems.
I want to have a order form with checkboxes for each product. User selects appropriate products and submits the order.

I cannot get the form to create the correct hash.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_id, :user_id

  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_id, :product_id, :order_id

  belongs_to :orders
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Here the view:

```
<%= form_for 'line_items[]' do |f|  %>
   <%= f.select :account_id, options_from_collection_for_select( Account.all, 
       :id, :name ), :prompt => 'Select Account' %>

<% Product.all.each do |product| %>
<div>
       <%= check_box_tag 'line_items[product_ids][]', product.id %>
</div>
<% end -%>

    <div>       
    <%= f.submit 'save' %>
</div>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model to enable nested atributes from associated models. You may also want to check out this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=asciicast) and adapt to your needs.

For example in the orders model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_id, :user_id

  has_many :products #This makes the association to products
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products #This allows the attributes from products accessible
end
```

Then the form could be:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>

  <%= f.select :account_id, options_from_collection_for_select( Account.all, 
       :id, :name ), :prompt => 'Select Account' %>

  <%= f.fields_for :product do |product_form| %>
    <%= product_form.check_box :id  %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok. but **(1)** how do i load all products in my order view for selection and **(2)** generate multiple records in case somebody selected multiple products? You see i have the line_items table which holds references for order and products. does that make sense? **(1)** `<% Product.all.each do |product| %>
<div>
       <%= check_box_tag 'line_items[product_ids][]', product.id %>
</div>
<% end -%>`

Comment: jason! you right. i had to change the models around to get it work with nested attributes. thanks.